# Java assignment - getting some weird values from my calculations

Tags: java, methods, return, coordinates, trigonometry

I'm learning Java right now and one of my assignments has got me pretty stumped. I'm being asked to create a class which designates a coordinate in the first quadrant of a Cartesian plane and do so using only two values: the distance from said point to the origin (0,0) and the angle that vector draws to the X axis. The program looks like this so far:

```
public class Point2 {
    private double _radius;
    private double _alpha;

    public Point2 (int x, int y) {
        this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
    }

    public Point2 (Point2 other) {
        this._radius = other._radius;
        this._alpha = other._alpha;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return (int)(this._radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this._alpha)));
    }

    public int getY() {
        return (int)(this._radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this._alpha)));
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        if(x > 0) {
            this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(this.getY(), 2));
            this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(this.getY(), x));
        }
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        if(y > 0) {
            this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
            this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, this.getX()));
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Point2 other) {
        if(this._radius == other._radius && this._alpha == this._radius) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAbove(Point2 other) {
        if(this.getY() > other.getY()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isUnder(Point2 other) {
        if(this.getY() < other.getY()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isLeft(Point2 other) {
        if(this.getX() < other.getX()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRight(Point2 other) {
        if(this.getX() > other.getX()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    double distance(Point2 other) {
        double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.getX() - other.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(this.getY() - other.getY(), 2));

        return dist;
    }

    public void move(int dX, int dY) {
        if(this.getX() + dX > 0 && this.getY() + dY > 0) {
            this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.getX() + dX, 2) + Math.pow(this.getY() + dY, 2));
            this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(this.getY() + dY, this.getX() + dX));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + _radius + "," + _alpha + ")";
    }
}
```

Anyway, what happens when I create an instance of this class given x and y coordinates there's really no problem -- the calculations come out correctly and everything is just fine. The trouble is when I try to use any of the methods that change the X or Y coordinates.

For example, I'll run the `setX(10)` and when I run `getX()`, I'll get 9, but when I run `setX(10)` again and then rerun `get(X)`, I'll get 10. The same goes for `move()` - calling the method once returns an inaccurate result for `getX()` and `getY()` but calling the method with the same parameters once or twice more will correct the result.

It's weird - almost like the calculations here are incorrect or there's a rounding problem. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely running into rounding errors. The first way to solve this would be to store x and y directly. Generally storing calculated data is a bad idea. However, I'm assuming this isn't possible.

You're running into two problems.

in this code:

```
this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(this.getY(), 2));
this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(this.getY(), x));
```

Note that `this.getY()` depends on both radius and alpha. When you change the radius in the first call, the value you get from getY will be different in the second call! You want to cache the value returned from `getY`:

```
int y = this.getY();
this._radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
this._alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
```

The same problem is found in setY, with getX changing mid-function.

The other problem you're getting is due to casting a double to an integer in getX/getY. Java does this by truncation: `(int) 4.99999999` will become `4`. It's likely that you will get better results by using `(int) Math.round(...)` (Math.round() returns a long if you pass a double).

#### In conclusion

- If at all possible, change your code to store x and y directly, you can compute the angle and radius based off those values.
- Consider that x and y could be non-integers. Why are you limiting them to integers?
- Be careful, the state of an object might not be consistent while you are in the process of modifying it, e.g. `getY` isn't safe to call when you've only modified the radius based on the new x value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -- the problem here is that I'm being specifically requested not to use variables other than _radius and _alpha, and I have no idea how my professor expects me to do it otherwise because obviously the solution you just presented is ideal, to say the least.

To answer your question I'm limiting x and y to integers because, again, that's what I'm being asked to do. The assignment clearly states that x and y are integers which place the point in the first quadrant of a Cartesian plane.

Comment: I changed the code as per your recommendation and it works like a charm. Thanks!